# Issue with Deep Linking in Facebook using Fireabse

Tags: android, ios, facebook, firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

I have issue with deep linking in android and iOS,Iam using firebase and i've got url to myApp https://xxxxx.app.goo.gl

First case: When i open this URL in Notes app,it works fine and open myApp if installed.

Second case: from facebook.com in safari or any browser,it works fine and open myApp if installed.

Third case: opening the same link from facebook app directs me to the internal browser of Facebook and give me "400 Not Found" as if iam opening the link from safari

So,what can i do to use deep linking in Facebook app to open my App ??

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to do something with it? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Comment: check that u added url scheme in "ius" key as following:
xxxx.app.goo.gl/?link="link"&ibi="bundleIdentifier"&ius="urlScheme"